# What does "At least X to Y" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, speech

What does it mean to say "at least..." and then give a range of values?

"At least 10" means anything greater than or equal to ten.

"10 to 15" means anything greater than or equal to 10, but not greater than 15.

I hear it in everyday speak all the time. A teacher might assign a report that "must be at least 10-15 pages." What does that mean? Does she mean that the paper must be 10-15 pages, or does she mean that a lower bound on the pages we need to write, has not been decided, but will be in the range of 10 to 15? Or does she just mean *at least 10*?

- What does “at least ten to fifteen pages” mean?

Comment: Down votes because...?

Comment: Well it is a boundary together with an error estimate. It's like saying John is 6 feet tall, give or take half-an-inch.  However I don't like the usage. Where did you find it?

Comment: I hear it in everyday speak all the time. A teacher might assign a report that "must be at least 10-15 pages." What does that mean? Does she mean that the paper must be 10-15 pages, or does she mean that a lower bound on the pages we need to write, has not been decided, but will be in the range of 10 to 15? Or does she just mean at least 10?

Comment: I'll presume to give an example. A recipe book might say "Leave in the oven for 10 to 15 minutes, or until golden brown."  If someone asks *"How long will it take to turn golden brown?"*, I might reply *"Oh, at least 10 to 15 minutes."*  It just means that the minimum value is approximate.

Comment: @Doop - the teacher knows that if she says "at least 10 pages", every report she receives will have 11 pages. It's too specific, and the students will think of it as a target, rather than a guide.

Comment: @Doop - you ask about down-votes. If you had given that last comment as your question instead of the rather fragmentary version you actually typed, I think you would have avoided the down-votes.  Context makes all the difference - people appreciate it. An example makes it clear what you are asking and it makes the job of answering easier.

Comment: I upvoted because I think this is a legitimate question. It is sometimes  tempting to attribute mere peevishness to someone who raises an issue like this one, but I think that the poster here genuinely wants to understand the logic underlying the phrase "at least 10 to 15"—and that makes it a valid question about English usage.

Answer (score 2):

It is very sloppy English, and as you noted, has no clear mathematical interpretation.  Ask your teacher whether she meant to say:

- At least 10, but no more than 15 pages

or did she mean

- at least 10 to 15 pages, or longer if you like.

Keep in mind that spacing and margin variations could make one student's 15-page paper no longer than another student's 10-page paper, so she might actually be referring to *the same length* when she mentions 10-to-15.

To be clear, accurate and fair, she might say (for example) "The paper needs to be between 2000 and 3000 words."

Comment: Good point about the possibility that the teacher might have meant to set 15 pages as the upper limit on page length—and a solid answer all around.